# Drupal 7 module not loading JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal-7

I am trying to load a JavaScript file for my module. The javascript code should execute and dynamically apply some CSS styling.

However, my jQuery is not having any effect. Plain vanilla JavaScript code works but not my jQuery code.

I am loading my JavaScript with the following code:

```
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module') .'/js/mycode.js', 'file');
```

I'm applying this code outside of any function but loaded it in `hook_node_view` when the `$view_mode` is **full**.

And the following is my javascript:

```
(function ($) {

    alert('RESPONDING!');

    $('#page').css('background', 'red')

    alert('RESPONDING-2!');


    jQuery('body').click(
        function () {
            alert('clicked!');
        }
    );

})(jQuery);
```

Nothing `$/jQuery` tagged works but both alert statements work.

Comment: what is $('#page') reffering to? make sure $('#page') is a valid html element

Comment: div#page is a valid element. I am actually pasting the same code into Chrome's console and it works as expected

Comment: is it available to the time of point when you try to access it?

Comment: That's where I was a bit unsure. There is no real reason why it could not be available but, just in case, I used hook_node_view and only load the js when the page is fully loaded

Comment: you may test it easily just log  $('#page')  to console right before you access it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Thariama:

Thanks for all your input and ideas.

Your suggestion to console.log($('#page')) was very instructive. I realized something was seriously wrong when the output came out entirely empty. It go me thinking and I decided to try relocating the code to "the bottom of the page".

With the following modified code:

```
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module') .'/js/mycode.js', array('type' => 'file', 'scope' => 'footer'));
```

My **$/jQuery** tagged code now executes.

Thanks!